# React Native Bluetooth background scan

Tags: react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to scan devices on IOS when the app is in background mode. I've learned that I have to tell explicitly what service ID I'm looking for. I was trying with 180F which is the battery service but it didn't find anything. Is it possible at all on IOS? It works well on Android.

I'm using the react-native-ble-manager package.

Can you tell me maybe a common service UUID what every phone advertises?

My aim is to track every contact with phones which are nearby me and it should work when the app is in background mode.